# Mysqli command is not working, can we write column name price-1?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$q = "update men SET price-1='$first' WHERE id='1'";

if($db->query($q))
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Data Has Been Updated Successfully ')</script>";
    }
```

The error in the column name price-1, If my column name is like price then it works but not with price-1

Comment: Do you mean `$q = "update men SET price='$first'-1 WHERE id='1'";` instead ?

Comment: Do you have a column called `price-1`, or are you trying to reduce the value of the price column by one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to escape your column name

```
$q = "update men SET `price-1`='$first' WHERE id='1'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround the column name price-1 in quotes 'price-1' and try again. The quote is this ` just it won't let me write it. It's the one under the Escape. I noticed my mystake.

Comment: Why don't you make the column name price_1 or price1. That hyphen is hard and annoying to handle. I suggest not using it when naming be it variables, column names, etc. Not that it's impossible but it's just unneccessary pain.

Comment: yeah, you are write, thnaks for helping me.